# Properties of a vector system.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me with this example.  An explanation will be very nice, even if you let me make the exercise.  Is an example of an extra material I receive in my algebra class.

Let $V = \{(x, y) \mid x, y \in\mathbb R\}$ the set in which the operations of addition and multiplication by a scalar are defined as follows:

---

$$v_1 + v_2 = (x_1, y_1) + (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2)\quad \forall v_1, v_2 \in V .$$

$$kv = k (x, y) = (kx, 0),\quad \forall v \in V,\ \ \ k \in\mathbb R$$

Determine the property that prevents not satisfied $v$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R.$

Comment: What element could you make the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the axioms for V being a vector is that for every $v \in V$, $1 \cdot v = v$ ([Identity element of scalar multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)). But from the definition of the scalar multiplication you provide for $V$:

> $kv=k(x,y)=(kx,0), \quad ∀v∈V,\ k∈ℝ,$

it follows that
$1\cdot (2,3) = (1\cdot 2, 0)=(2,0) \neq (2,3)$ which is a contradiction to the above mentioned axiom. Thus $V$ can't be a vector space.

Comment: Is still not clear to me... do you have more hints?

Comment: Is it now more understandable to you?